# シェルスクリプトで特定の文字列のイコールの後ろの文字列を取得

Tags: bash, shellscript, solaris

Solaris上でシェルスクリプト（bash）にて、CSV形式ファイルから取得した1行毎の文字列の中から、特定の文字列のイコールの後ろのカンマ前までの文字列を抜き取りたいのですが、正規表現の書き方が解りません。どうかご教授いただけますでしょうか。

（例）
a=aaa,b=bbb,c=ccc,d=ddd,e=eee
a=aaa,c=ccc,d=ddd,e=eee,f=fff
b=bbb,c=ccc,d=ddd,e=eee,g=ggg
　　　　：

上記の例で、"d="の後ろの”ddd"を取得したいです。
"d="は必須項目なのですが、"a="や"b="は必須ではない為、
データが無い場合もあり、"d="の出現順序は固定ではありません。

Comment: 文字列を抜き取りだした後の出力例(イメージ)を質問文に書くと、より良い回答がもらえる可能性があります。 (抜き出した文字列を改行区切りで羅列すればよいのか、文字列の重複を排除してソートするのか等)

Comment: 正規表現処理に使うツールは既に頭の中にあるのでしょうか。あるならばそのツールを書いたほうが良いです。（正規表現にも方言？があるので）

Comment: 文字列を抜き出した後の出力（処理）イメージですが、CSVファイルから１行ずつ読み込んだ文字列の中から期待の値を取得し、その値をDBのキーとして使用してselectすることをしようとしています。CSVファイルから取得したそれぞれの１行の中に同じ項目が重複（”d=”が複数存在）することやソートする要件はありません。

また、正規表現に使うツール（コマンド）は「sed」を想定しています。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳なかったのですが、動作させたい対象のOSはSolarisで、お教えいただいたsedコマンドはLinuxでは取得できたのですが、Solarisでは取得できませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

bash の built-in command だけを使うのであれば以下の様に、

```
$ while IFS=, read -ra l
  do
    for((i=0;i<${#l[@]};i++))
    do
      [[ ${l[$i]} =~ ^d=.+ ]] && printf '%s\n' "${l[$i]#d=}"
    done
  done < data.csv
```

GNU grep を使っても良いのであれば以下の様にもできます。

```
$ grep -Po '((?<=,d=)|(?<=^d=))(.+?)(?=(,|$))' data.csv
```

ただ、どちらとも d の値が無い場合(以下の様な行)は何も出力しません。

```
a=aaa,b=bbb,c=ccc,d=,e=eee
```

**追記**

Solaris + sed との事ですが、tr コマンドと組み合わせて以下の様にしてみると良いかもしれません。

```
$ tr , '\n' < data.csv | sed -n 's/^d=//p'
```

なお、手元に Solaris 環境がないため結果については未確認です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
 grepコマンドは、Linuxでは取得できたのですが、Solarisでは「”-o”のオプションが無い」というエラーになり取得できませんでした。builtinCommand の方は現在確認中です。

Comment: tr コマンドと sed を組み合わせた方法を追記してみました。

Comment: Solaris上で「while IFS= 」のbuiltinCo‌​mmandパターンと「trとsedを組み合わせた」パターンの両方共、動きました。d=が無い場合は何も出力されませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

自分が実際にやるなら、てっとり早くこんな感じで処理すると思います。

```
$ grep -o 'd=[^,]*' in.csv | sed -e 's/^d=//'
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Linuxでは取得できたのですが、Solarisでは「”-o”のオプションが無い」というエラーになりました。

Answer (score 0):

sed なら


`sed -n 's/^.*d=\([^,]\+\).*$/\1/p'`


「d=」が無い行は無視されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Linuxでは取得できたのですが、Solarisでは取得できませんでした。

Comment: `\+` は存在しないので、`[^,]\+` の箇所を `[^,][^,]*` に書き換えて使ってください。
<https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=regexp&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=SunOS+5.10&arch=default&format=html>

Comment: sed -n 's/^.*d=\([^,][^,]*\).*$/\1/p'
Solaris上で動きました。d=の無い行は無視されました。ありがとうございました。